# The "a new answer was posted" quick refresh won't update the answer counter properly

Tags: bug

So you make a question and leave the page open.

Then a grey box appears saying "a new answer was posted - click here to refresh". So you click it.

The answer appears alright, but the answer counter says "N" instead of "N Answers". You have to do a manual refresh to see the correct form.

Look, it says "2":

[image: Screenshot of malformed answer counter]

But this is how it should look:

[image: Screenshot of correct answer counter]

I might have seen this occur on other SE sites, not sure.

I'm using Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63 with Mac OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: Is anyone else experiencing this?